# Java SQL: use previously existing result sets

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, caching, view

I wasn't able to find the answers in other locations so I ask this now.

I am using embedded PostgreSQL and java.sql to execute Java queries.

I have a query that I want to execute as follows:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM table1 WHERE table2id in cachedTable1" + 
                        "AND table3id in " +
                        "(SELECT id FROM table3 WHERE string2 = ?) " +
                        "AND (table3id, table2id) NOT IN " +
                        "(SELECT table3id, table2id " +
                        "FROM table1 " +
                        "WHERE table2id in " +
                        "(SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE string1 = ?) " +
                        "AND table3id in " +
                        "(SELECT id FROM table3 WHERE string2 = ?) LIMIT 1)"))
```

However, what I end up doing is executing these nested queries twice:

```
(SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE string1 = ?)
```

...and...

```
(SELECT id FROM table3 WHERE string2 = ?)
```

What I want to do is only have these execute once. For example, I want to store those queries in two different result sets, AND be able to reference them in my query, like so:

```
 PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM table1 WHERE table2id in cachedTable1" + 
                            "AND table3id in " +
                            "cachedTable2 " +
                            "AND (table3id, table2id) NOT IN " +
                            "(SELECT table3id, table2id " +
                            "FROM table1 " +
                            "WHERE table2id in " +
                            "cachedTable1 " +
                            "AND table3id in " +
                            "cachedTable2 LIMIT 1)"))
```

...where we can assume that the results of the first nested query are stored in cachedTable1 and the results of the second query are stored in cachedTable2.

I've glossed briefly over some answers and some seem to suggest that I can't do something like this in Native Java, and also that views can't be supported in native Java. Is there a way to implement this query caching?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use the [with](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) clause (also known as CTE) with the `PerparedStatement`:

```
WITH table3_ids AS (SELECT id FROM table3 WHERE string2 = ?)
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE
    table2id in cachedTable1
    AND table3id in table3_ids
    AND (table3id, table2id) NOT IN 
        (SELECT table3id, table2id 
         FROM table1 
         WHERE table2id in 
         (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE string1 = ?) 
    AND table3id in  table3_ids
LIMIT 1)
```

As far as I can look it up on the web, CTE with clause acts as a temporary table. It would be good to experiment with that though..

Comment: I just did some research, you can't use WITH with DELETE, only with SELECT.

Comment: That;'s true in Oracle. However, postrges seems to support it. If you check the page I linked https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html you'll find example for that, e.g.  the one that starts with `WITH RECURSIVE included_parts`